# What's the difference between async operator and subscribing to observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I am new to Angular and RxJs and Ngrx

I know that we subscribe to an Observable and watch for changes. I came across this code in Ngrx [getting started](https://ngrx.io/guide/store)

```
<div>Current Count: {{ count$ | async }}</div>
```

Question is what exactly is [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) and how its different from subscribing to an Observable ? and when is one used and when the other?

Comment: It's not different really, it's how you subscribe in the template.

Comment: Don't, then; it's up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe mentioned it isn't really different.  Under the hood the async pipe will create a subscription and store the most recent value which is the same thing that you would need to do if you wanted to subscribe and display the result.

The `async` pipe will also take care of unsubscribing from the observable when the component (the directive) is destroyed.

It *may* be slightly more efficient in terms of change detection but I'm not certain.

Mostly however, it is just used for convenience.  It is less code to use an `async` pipe than it is to create a component variable and subscribe to it in the component's `onInit` or constructor and then keep track of the subscription to unsubscribe.

Comment: I think  the main differene is async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise, you can use Async with a Promise too and same is not true for Subscription ?

Comment: It is definately more effecient if you change you components to use changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Comment: @dota2pro The syntax is different but you should be able to get the result from a promise into a local component variable just like you can for an observable.

Answer (score 9):

async pipe is much cleaner

```
data$ = this.service.data$;
```

and in the template

```
{{data$ | async}}
```

vs having to manage the subscription.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.service.data$.subscribe(data => { this.data = data });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

and in the template

```
{{data}}
```