# Benefit of async pipe vs traditional subscription

Tags: angular

From my understanding of async pipe, it's a quicker way of subscribing to an observable in fewer lines. However I'm trying to understand in what circumstances would I need to use it over a traditional subscription like my current component below?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from "./services/http.service";
import { Main } from "./interfaces/data-interface";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
  }

  mainData: Main;
  itemIndexFocus: number = 0;


  ngOnInit() {

    this.httpService.getFighterDetail()
            .subscribe((res) => {
              this.mainData = res.body;
            });
  }
}
```

httpservice file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getFighterDetail(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("/MYAPI", { responseType: 'json', observe: 'response' })
    }


}
```

It is just a case that I could always use async pipe? If I'm populating a reactiveform with values from an api then I guess my above component's approach would be the more beneficial one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011836/whats-the-difference-between-async-operator-and-subscribing-to-observable).

Http is an observable that is automatically complete once the reponse is receive so it a nonsense to use a async pipe on it.

Async pipe is really powerfull with NgRx. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707721/ngrxstore-and-angular-use-the-async-pipe-massively-or-subscribe-just-once-in-t) you can find few lines about subscribe vs async pipe

Answer (score 1):

Pipes are used to modify the data / add extra logic & other fun stuff to an observable. Pipes do not "subscribe" to an observable

Yeah you could definitely not use pipes, but then you are missing out on the functionality & cleaner code they provide

For example, if you have some user service that gets a list of users from your API, you'll have to also account for when the server is unavailable, or returns an error code.

Let's say multiple components use this user service, do you want to add error handing to all your components? That's pretty messy. Alternatively in the service you can pipe your error handling

This way each component that needs users doesn't have to care about error handling